# Roots of an equation of order $4$.

Tags: calculus, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $At^4+Bt^3+Ct^2+Dt+E$ and $A,B,C,D,E \in \mathbb{R}$. What can you say about the coefficients $A,B,C,D,E$ if this equation is always required to be negative (for all $t$)? What is the relation between these coefficients?

Comment: What do you get if $t=0$? Or $t=\infty$ (i.e. really large)?

Comment: It's an expression, or a function of $t$, not an equation.

Answer (score 2):

it factors with real numbers $p,q,r,s$ as
$$  A (t^2 + pt+q)(t^2 + rt + s)  $$
with
$$ 4q > p^2 \; , $$
$$ 4s > r^2 \; ,     $$
so both $q,s > 0.$

Indeed, as they are positive reals, we can define
$$ u^2 = q - \frac{p^2}{4} \; , $$
$$ v^2 = s -  \frac{r^2}{4} \; , $$
and your polynomial as the negative constant $A$ times a sum of squares,
$$ A  \left( \left( t + \frac{p}{2} \right)^2 \left( t + \frac{r}{2} \right)^2  + v^2 \left( t + \frac{p}{2} \right)^2 + u^2 \left( t + \frac{r}{2} \right)^2 + u^2 v^2  \right) $$

Comment: That would imply that $A<0$, as $E=Aqs$ and we can tell from $t=0$ that $E<0$

Comment: From the graph I've constructed, the values of $B,C, D$ seem irrelevant (the function seems always negative so long as $A,E<0$). Pehaps someone can verify this assertion, although I'm not sure as yet how quite to do that. Graph here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g0mztpttdp

Comment: @RhysHughes graph $- (t^4 - 9t + 1)$

Comment: @RhysHughes: $B$, $C$, $D$ are certainly not irrelevant. Your Desmos graph is zoomed-out really-really-really far, which isn't helpful. Zoom-in close to the origin, with $x$ values between, say, $10$ and $-10$, and *then* start fiddling with your $B$, $C$, $D$ sliders.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed there are exceptions, however it seems for the large majority of cases the dominant factor is that $A<0$